# LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, wamp

I was configuring my wamp server (I am following a tutorial of cakephp on the official site) so I didnt find this instruction in the httpd.conf  once I add it the server it cant restart services then stick in the orange color so any one had the same problem ?? please help !
(I think the problem is in (libexec) but I have no Idea of what to do ..

Comment: Is the rewrite module installed on your server? (Which server OS are you using?)

Comment: @J.M. Wamp is a bundle of apache-mysql-php for windows systems, it contains all needed modules.

Answer (score 0):

You need to click on the wamp icon to bring the menu up, then apache->apache modules and check rewrite_module (it may be down on the list so make sure to go down until you find it.

If you've made any config changes in httpd.conf try to roll the file back to the original because you may have brought changes that will confuse the server.

Then just to make sure, restart all services (from wamp menu) and you ought to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

In this directory: (I am using Ubuntu 12.10)

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

You should search below content, it has been installed:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

in terminal

Comment: He is using wamp - windows version